# Using const_missing to refer to a class external from the module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, class-constants

I have an app with this folder structure:

```
# /app/controllers/first_controller.
class FirstController
  def method
    'External'
  end
end

# /app/controllers/second_controller.rb
class SecondController
  def method
    'External'
  end
end

# /app/controllers/foo/first_controller.rb
module Foo
  class FirstController < ::FirstController
    def method
      'Internal'
    end
  end
end
```

My desidered behaviour is:

```
Foo::FirstController#method => "Internal"

Foo::SecondController#method => "External"
```

So, if the controller is not defined in the module `Foo`, it should instantiate the external cass

I tried creating a file `foo.rb`:

```
# /app/controllers/foo.rb
module Foo
  def self.const_missing(name)
    "::#{name}".constantize
  end
end
```

But using this makes rails ignore all the classes defined under `/app/controllers/foo/*.rb` (does not require them at all).

How can I obtain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just let Rails to do the job if the class exists in `Foo` namespace. It uses `const_missing` to resolve the class names too:

```
module Foo
  def self.const_missing(name)
    if File.exists?("app/controllers/foo/#{name.to_s.underscore}.rb")
      super
    else
      "::#{name}".constantize
    end
  end
end
```

Output:

```
Foo::FirstController.new.method
# => "Internal" 
Foo::SecondController.new.method
# => "External"
```